# Send Data And Get Response between (Python on Raspberry pi) and (Matlab on PC)

Tags: python, matlab

i want to perform communication between (Python on raspberrypi) and (Matlab on PC). Raspberry pi performs face detection and crop faces. i need to send these faces to matlab on pc for processing (face recognition) and retrieve back the label from matlab to python on raspi i have searched all over the internet but couldn't find a detail explaination.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest alternative is [using TCP/IP socekts:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/using-tcpip-server-sockets.html)

There's also the [Serial Port](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.html), but the RPI doesn't come with a usb2com adaptor, so you'll need to purchase one.

You could also transmit over USB by configuring the usb port as a virutal serial port. I've only done it on bare metal ARM cortex, but it should be possible to do that on the RPI too.